# jquery not applying css after pagination

Tags: jquery

This may have been asked many times before but I am not able to solve. I have to apply css on background of first column of dynamic table. My code is  working fine on first page. but while navigating to next page it is not working

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
                                 $('table tr').find('td:eq(0)').css('background','#red');
                        });
```

I have tried above code inside `$(document).on('page/load/change','table tr, function(){})` and is breaking and not even working on first page.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Correct your css property name. $('table tr').find('td:eq(0)').css('background-color', 'red');

Comment: thanks for reply, but it is working fine with 'background' only

Comment: Yup, css property name does not seem to be the problem. I suggest you to solve this with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this just with CSS.

```
/*Set background color on the first column*/

td:nth-child(1) { 
   background-color: red; 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. can you help me in another problem that I have two columns. and this css is working but I have to frooze those 2 columns. but they are overlapping while scrolling. can you point me on to solve that

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by columns overlapping. Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: wait, let me make one

Comment: Check the above fiddle. I added css to th1 and th2.

Comment: thank you, but the problem I am trying to solve here is that, width is generated dynamically and therefore I have to assign `left` for second column as `(width of first)-width of table.` this is where it is breaking.